# Why does LTSpice simulation give me negative value on NPN emitter current?

Tags: transistors, ltspice, npn

So I built this circuit and I am trying to measure the emitter current, and the LTSpice simulation is giving me negative value reading... any idea why?
[image]

Comment: Negative currents are **out of** a pin. Positive currents are **into** a pin. The sum of all the currents into and out of the BJT should be zero. (The BJT isn't a Coulomb bucket.)

Comment: @Jonk why not 'answer' the question?

Comment: @Huisman Because I'd feel a need to provide more detail and explanation. I don't have the time for that. Sure, a lot of people here do write very short answers, collect a bunch of points for it, and feel fine about it. I don't. I don't think you can find a single short answer here without my taking time for context -- well, there is one but I'm not telling on myself! I may be wrong about my answers. I obviously make mistakes and have wrong ideas. But I do provide the context from which I'm coming. I just don't have the time right now to provide an answer with my name on it. Maybe later?

Comment: @jonk I understand and very much like your style not to write cheap answers!

Comment: Always make sure to look a the mouse cursor direction arrow when you click somewhere to display a current. In LTSpice, even passive components like resistors will have a pre-defined direction for what a positive current represents and if you put the resistor into the circuit the wrong way around, the graph will reflect this even though it will have no bearing on the function of the circuit.

Comment: @DKNguyen [This link](http://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelpXVII/LTspiceHelp/html/Trace_Selection.htm) seems to show the arrow only appears when hovering above a trace, not when hovering above a component's pin. Don't have LTspice on my phone, so cannot check this.

Comment: [This answer](https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/why-is-the-current-always-measured-negative-in-ltspice.40854/) claims that the current sign convention *uses the same convention for sources and loads, which is that + power is absorbing and - power is delivering.* Sounds very plausible to me.

Comment: @jonk isn't the same current convention used in the TTL series? The current out of a pin is a negative one?

Comment: @G36 I think that datasheets written in the 1960's and 1970's for TTL treat "sinking current" as "negative" and a sourcing current as "positive." But that's all context-sensitive. Once you know the rules of the road, it all just makes sense. Spice knows that IE=IC+IB and it makes a choice about which sign goes to IC and IB and which sign goes to IE. PNP, oppositely. I think Spice follows the datasheet approaches. Don't you?

Comment: @G36 Isn't IC on an NPN datasheet "positive?"

Comment: @jonk Yes, in NPN the Ic current is positive.

Comment: @Huisman Oh, really? huh. I don't know if that's the case either since I usually click on a component not a pin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I found in the Electronic Devices book by Stephen Fleeman.

> During the development of the V-I curves (and on manufacturers' data
>   sheets), it is customary to apply the transistor convention.  The
>   transistor convention has been defined in Fig. 4-10(a).
>
> **Currents that flow into the transistor are called positive.
>   Conversely, currents that flow out of the transistor are called
>   negative. If the actual conventional current directions agree with the
>   transistor convention, they are called positive. If not, they are
>   called negative**.
>   [image]

Comment: Good catch. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for explanation!