# Question regarding to LTspice diode simulation :

Tags: simulation, ltspice

[image]

While simulating using **.op analysis** for the forward bias of a diode in LTspice, it showing the **source current Iv1 in negative sign**. But, all the other currents are in positive sign. What does it mean?

[image]

Comment: I do not think these numbers are validated to KCL. It is just a matter of the graphical orientation of the symbol. For sanity check, try disconnect R1, rotate it 180 degrees and connect it again. Now, I believe you will change the sign of R1's current.

Comment: 0V-15V = -15V....

Comment: @Bonnevie OP asks about the voltage source, not the resistor. Probably OP (accidently?) rotated R1 such that it has the (expected) positive current.

Comment: @tuskiomi Your equation is correct, but makes no sense in this case. OP probably edited the schematic (incorrectly). The schematic as it is shown will result in an error:  ```Unknown parameter "-15v"```

Comment: @Huisman huh, I thought LT did arithmetic on it's parameters. I know it does with it's variables.

Comment: @tuskiomi it would if OP would have surrounded it with curly braces

Comment: @Huisman good point

Comment: @tuskiomi Moreover, I(D1) is positive, so, the voltage cannot be negative. Ow, and V(vin) = 0.5V in the same .op result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spice follows the passive sign convention: the positive current direction through a current or voltage source is from the positive node to the negative node.
Hence the negative sign.

You might find a resistor is sometimes also showing an unexpected sign. Probably Bonnevie is pointing that out.
Just rotate the resistor 180 degrees, or, download a resistor symbol with current arrow from [ltwiki.org](http://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=Most_frequently_asked_questions_for_beginners#Why_is_the_current_going_the_wrong_way_in_a_resistor.3F)

Answer (score 1):

The indications depend on how the LTSpice reads the voltage or current (R1.1 to R1.2) or (R1.2 to R1.1).

[Here](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/electrical-engineering/ee-circuit-analysis-topic/circuit-elements/a/ee-sign-convention) is a good source of some definitions.

As pointed out by  @Bonnevie, you can ignore it.

---

For the source current, the LTSpice treats all sources and resistors in the same at unlike how we write Kirchoff loop equations. To see the real direction of the current, place the current probe on the supply and observe the direction shown on the current probe when you place the mouse pointer on the voltage source.

---

Before rotating R1:
[image]

After rotating R1 by 180 degrees:
[image]

Comment: But the question is about the **source** current, not the resistor current.

Comment: Would like to see in LTspice tomorrow soon

Comment: The real source current direction can be seen when we see the current probe direction as well. Will capture it soon after I get hands on my PC

Answer (score 0):

Making the circuit more simpler,

[image]

we get,

[image]

You see the current flows out of the voltage source positive side, but gets a negative sign. This convention has a good intention, that is, positive power (IV) means consuming power, but negative power means delivering power. For example, the resister away gets positive power.

Comment: Try to rotate the resistor 180 degrees, and you should get a negative resistor current also.

Comment: @G36, true, but the power calculation still ends up positive if you use the convention, P=I_1to2 * V_1to2 (1, 2 are the two nodes of a resistor).

Comment: @G36 Moreover, the question isn't about the resistor.

Comment: @Huisman Yes, i know. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/470755/why-does-ltspice-simulation-give-me-negative-value-on-npn-emitter-current/470842#470842

Answer (score 0):

By convention in electrical measurements, power is positive for loads and **power is negative for generators or sources**.  This is done by defining load current as positive and **supply current as negative** and both with positive voltages.  It is the same for the grid where RMS power is technically negative for AC generators due to convention.